# How to build a dict of indices of occurences of elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the fastest way to convert the indices of occurrences of all elements in a list to a dict?

For e.g. :

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 , 2, 1 ]
```

I would like to build:

```
B['1'] = [0, 5]
B['2'] = [1, 4]
B['3'] = [2]
B['4'] = [3]
```

This is to avoid calling [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) several times in a loop which would be too slow for a large A. Ideally, would like to traverse the array A only once.
For example, want to avoid:

```
uniqA = np.unique(A)
for i in uniqA:
    B[str(i)] = np.argwhere(i==A)
```

Comment: Why do you want the keys to be strings?

Comment: Don't need them to be strings. Keys could be ints also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it iterating only once:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 , 2, 1 ]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,x in enumerate(A):
...    d[x].append(i)
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 5], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2], 4: [3]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, val in enumerate(A):
    d[val].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `defaultdict` is needed -- not sure if that is somehow better than this approach?

```
B={}
for i,x in enumerate(A):
    B[x]=B.get(x,[]) + [i]
```

Result:

```
{1: [0, 5], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2], 4: [3]}
```

Comment: You're creating a new list on every iteration and reassigning `B[x]` to it (an inefficiency that can matter with larger amounts of data). In this sort of case it makes more sense to append to the return value of `B.get(x,[])`, which modifies it in-place.

Comment: Interesting. Although you would get an error if you try appending to `[]`... (=`NoneType`) I just like avoiding `import` whenever possible.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with appending to `[]`, which is of type `list`.  You're probably assigning the return value of the `append()` call to `B[x]`.  In Python, by convention, side-effecting functions like `append()` return `None`.  You have to assign the object returned by `get()` to `B[x]` and append to it in different statements.